# Avoiding property name conflicts when building custom object

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to scrape a web page and build an object from table elements on the page. Sometimes each table element is unique, sometimes there are multiple elements with the same name.

If during the scrape I hit a second instance of a property, I want to name the new property numerically (continuing that sequence if I hit the name again).

I have managed to get this working per the below code, but is there a better way to do this?

```
$PropertyExists = $Object.PSObject.Properties.Name |
    Where { $_ -like "$PropertyName*" } | Sort -Descending | Select -First 1   

If ($PropertyExists) { 
    $PropertyNumber = [int]($PropertyExists -split "(\d+$)")[1] + 1 
} Else {
    $PropertyNumber = "" 
}

$Object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty 
    –Name "$PropertyName$PropertyNumber" 
    –Value $PropertyValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the property to a dynamic array if it's already defined:

```
$prop = $Object.$PropertyName
if ($prop -is [Collections.ArrayList]) {
    $prop.Add($PropertyValue) >$null
} elseif ($prop -is [object]) {
    $Object.$PropertyName = [Collections.ArrayList]@($prop, $PropertyValue)
} else {
    Add-Member @{$PropertyName = $PropertyValue} -InputObject $Object
}
```

Thus you'll be able to process uniformly both single-value and multi-value properties:

```
$Object.foo | ForEach { .... }
```

Another advantage is that we invoke the slow Add-Member much less frequently.

Comment: Great solution, thanks! The only small issue was that your code assumes the properties always have contents (and in my scenario they are sometimes blank) but I solved that by changing `elseif ($prop)` to `ElseIf ($Prop -is [object])`.